# Is it possible to use LuaRocks along with ZeroBraneStudio?

Tags: luarocks, zerobrane

I couldn't find a proper explanation on the internet or any tutorial on how to use LuaRocks with ZeroBraneStudio, is it possible?

I tried several ways myself, but nothing helped, there is information on the Internet how to install LuaRocks in ZeroBraneStudio, but it is either too complicated and long, or does not work at all, is there any simple and quick way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special to set up to run/debug a project that uses LuaRocks with ZeroBrane Studio. If you can run a project from a particular folder, then set that folder as a project folder in ZeroBrane Studio, execute run/debug commands, and it should all work. If it still doesn't work for you, then you need to post specific steps you're working through and the results you're getting (either by updating your comment or by opening a ticket for the project on github).

[update 2023-11-5] There is now a ZeroBrane Studio package that provides LuaRocks integration to install/manage packages: https://github.com/Propagram/ZeroBranePackage-LuaRocks